# Convert to binary notation in Haskell

Tags: haskell, binary, pattern-matching, data-conversion, idioms

Is there a better way to check `n` and `c` in this code, maybe with pattern matching  or something more Haskell-like?

```
toBin :: Int -> Int -> [Int]
toBin n c
    | n < 0 = []
    | c <= 0 = []
toBin n c = toBin (n `div` 2) (c - 1) ++ [n `mod` 2]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, they're both boolean expressions, so you can combine them with `||`

```
toBin n c | n < 0 || c <= 0 = []
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better here to work with an accumulator, which prevents making *O(n)* appends that result in an *O(n<sup>2</sup>)* algorithm in your code:

```
toBin :: Int -> Int -> [Int]
toBin = go []
  where go rs n c
          | n < 0 || c <= 0 = rs
          | otherwise = go (r:rs) q (c-1)
          where (q,r) = quotRem n 2
```

We here thus start with an empty list, and each time prepend the list with the next remainder until the number is zero, or the number of bits is 0.